# Livetでの画面遷移でちらつかない方法

Tags: c#, wpf

下記のコーディングで画面遷移しているのですが、`window.Hide()`をしてから遷移しますので、
今のwindowが隠れる為に、なにもない状態となって、次に遷移先のwindowが開きます。
よってちらつきが発生してしまいます。
ちらつきの回避と思って`window.Hide()`を画面遷移後(`Messenger.Raise()`の後)にすると
制御が戻っていない為に、遷移元のwindowも残ってしまいます。
遷移元のwindowが残らずに画面遷移する方法を教えて下さい。

```
// 現在の View のインスタンスを取得
var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault((w) => w.IsActive);
try
{
       // 現在の View を非表示
       window.Hide();
       // View にメッセージを送信～子画面をモーダルで起動
      Messenger.Raise(new TransitionMessage(new 
                 ViewModel2(),ShowCommand2"));   
}
finally
{
      // View を再表示する
      window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

本来は単一ウィンドウで画面遷移したいという事でしょうか。

それならば、 `ContentControl` を使うとDataContextにセットされたデータ型に応じて表示(View)を変えることが可能です。

以下は、Window.DataContextに連動してContentControlのViewを変えるサンプルです。

MainWindow.Xaml の Content部分

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="ViewModel1" Click="Button1_Click"/>
        <Button Content="ViewModel2" Click="Button2_Click" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- Window.DataContextとContentControl.DataContextを同期 -->
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <!-- 中身がViewModel1の時のView定義 -->
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel1}">
                <Label Content="ViewModel1" Background="PaleGreen"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <!-- 中身がViewModel2の時のView定義 -->
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel2}">
                <Label Content="ViewModel2" Background="PaleVioletRed"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.Xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new ViewModel1();
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new ViewModel2();
    }
}
```